# How can I use or implement the filters in extent reports

Tags: selenium-webdriver, extentreports

I am using the Extent html reporter. The ask is to click on the icons on the right hand side when I click on tick mark it should show the passed testcases when I click on cross mark it should show the failed testcases and so on[image of icons in html report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtGuJ.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think that this functionality has slowly decayed overtime. It's not even in the current release -> 5.0.9. The last stable release with this feature working as intended is 2.4.1 and is under relevantstack instead of aventstack